# How can I populate a form with an @Input() value that is of type object?

Tags: angular, angular-material, fullcalendar

This is the ts with the input that i was mentioning

```
 @Input() event: ClassEvent //this is the input
  start-date: FormControl;
  end-date: FormControl;
  class : FormControl;
  myForm: FormGroup;
```

And this is a part of the form

```
 <div class="form-group">
 <select id="location_id" formControlName="class"
                required>
                <option value="" disabled selected>Classes</option>
                <option *ngFor="let class of classList">
                    {{class.name}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `patchValue` is what you're after. It's a method you'll find on your `FormGroup`.
As an example...

```
ngOnInit(){
  // ...
  myForm.patchValue(selectedEvent);
}
```

More information here - https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms